# Export obj with tga textures to obj with png textures using blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am new to Blender. Is there a way to export a model with tga textures to a model with png textures. I tried multiple times but to no avail. What I mean is that when I export the model to obj, the mtl file would direct the newly made png textures(from the tga textures) to the newly exported model. Is there a way for this to happen in Blender? Please help me.

When I loaded the obj file and the mtl file in Blender, I put the tga texture directly to it. The tga fits properly with the loaded obj. Now I want to export the obj with png textures. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in blender... baking.  But it is the most complicated way to do what you want.

The more efficient method, would be to open the images in Photoshop, Gimp, inkscape, or whatever, and just save them as png files.

Then, in blender you can just swap the textures of the material. Or instead of placing the .tgas place the newly created .png files.

You should just be able to save the edits.

Comment: obj is just a text file no? You can directly change the file in the obj.